# Primes and Finite Field Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> Determine all primes $p>0$ so that there exists a solution in $\mathbb F_p$, the field with $p$ elements.
>   $$a)\  3x^2 - 30x+40=0$$
>   $$b)\ x^2 + 26x+139=0$$
>   $$c)\ x^2 - 5x+6=0$$

For a), I got p=2, p=13. For b), I got p=5, p=31, for c), I got p=3. Could someone please tell me if there is an easier way to calculate all the prime p instead of brute forcing it? Could you also please let me know if these are all the primes p that satisfies the condition?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Hint: complete the square and use quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: @Oiler Thanks for the hint. I am trying to learn it right now. It was never taught in lecture. This question was in my final exam.....

Comment: The quadratic formula gives the solution whenever $p\neq2$. In that case you are to figure out when the discriminant is a square modulo $p$ (for the solution to be in $\Bbb{F}_p$ you need to be able to take the square root). You have to check the case $p=2$ separately, because then the quadratic formula doesn't make sense (neither does completing the square). Check: In all the cases you get an infinite collection of primes as the answer.

Comment: For (a) you missed $(p=5,x=0)$ and $(p=7,x=5).$ The previous comments should help. There is also the (not easy) theorem that if $A,B\in \mathbb N$ with $\gcd (A,B)=1$ then $\{An+B: n\in \mathbb N\} $contains infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 0):

In c) we have $$x^2-5x+6=(x-2)(x-3)$$ so $x=2$ and $x=3$ are solutions modulo any prime $p$.

In b) we have
$$
x^2+26x+139=(x+13)^2-30.
$$
So this quadratic has a solution modulo $p$, if and only if $30=2\cdot3\cdot5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. In other words we need an even number of $2,3,5$ to be quadratic non-residues modulo $p>5$. By the law of quadratic reciprocity i) the question about $2$ depends on the residue class of $p$ modulo $8$, ii) the question about $3$ depends on the residue class of $p$ modulo $12$, and iii) the question about $5$ depends on the residue class of $p$ modulo $5$. A consequence of this is that the answer depends on the residue class of $p$ modulo $\mathrm{lcm}(8,12,5)=120$. Leaving it to you to check how the $\phi(120)=32$ residue classes split (it works for exactly one half of them and doesn't work for the other half).

Part a) is similar to part b). Leaving that to you as well. Apart from the factors of the discriminant (that you need to check separately), there will be a fifty-fifty split among the primes according to their residue class modulo a suitable number.